# Bootstrap - Layout of Radio Buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage that uses Bootstrap 3. In this page, I have some radio buttons. Some of them have short labels. Some have longer labels. I'd like to format my radio buttons so that they render like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| o Choice 1                                           |
|                                                      |
| o Choice 2. This is a longer label that should       |
|   wrap. Notice how the wrap does not happen under    |
|   the radio button. Rather the text is justified     |
|                                                      |
| o Choice 3                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

In an attempt to do this, I decided to use `display:inline-block;`, but that's not working. I'd really like to use `inline-flex`. However, I can't use that because of my target browsers. So, I tried mimicing this functionality using straight HTML. I've created that in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jZ6Uk1Msjm). Yet, the wrapping behavior is still incorrect. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myChoices">
        <label class="choice">
            <input id="SelectedStation" name="SelectedStation" type="radio" value="1">
            <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
            <p>ABC</p>
        </label>
        <br>

        <label class="choice">
            <input id="SelectedStation" name="SelectedStation" type="radio" value="2">
            <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
            <p>CBS</p></label>
        <br>

        <label class="choice">
            <input id="SelectedStation" name="SelectedStation" type="radio" value="3">
            <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
            <p> This is a longer label that should wrap. Notice how the wrap does not happen under the radio button. Rather the text is justified</p>
        </label>
        <br>

        <label class="choice">
            <input id="SelectedStation" name="SelectedStation" type="radio" value="4">
            <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
            <p>NBC</p>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

What did I do wrong? Why is a) the label appearing on the line below the radio button and b) why isn't the text wrapping inline with the label?

Thank you

Comment: `p` tags are block tags (takes entire width of the page) , you can replace with `span` tag

Comment: @PavanKumarJorrigala I can't do that. Unfortunately, the `p` blocks have been generated by a third-party library. I have control over the sibbling `input` and `span` tags. I also have control over the parent `label` tags on up (including the class names and definitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can't use the same `id` more than once in a single page; so use a `.SelectedStation` class instead.

Secondly, you can use `relative` positioning on `.choice`, `absolute` positioning on `.SelectedStation` and apply some left padding to your `<p>`s.

```css
.choice {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.SelectedStation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.choice p {
  padding-left: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="myChoices">
    <label class="choice">
      <input class="SelectedStation" name="SelectedStation" type="radio" value="1">
      <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
      <p>ABC</p>
    </label>
    <br>

    <label class="choice">
      <input class="SelectedStation" name="SelectedStation" type="radio" value="2">
      <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
      <p>CBS</p>
    </label>
    <br>

    <label class="choice">
      <input class="SelectedStation" name="SelectedStation" type="radio" value="3">
      <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
      <p>This is a longer label that should wrap. Notice how the wrap does not happen under the radio button. Rather the text is justified</p>
    </label>
    <br>

    <label class="choice">
      <input class="SelectedStation" name="SelectedStation" type="radio" value="4">
      <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
      <p>NBC</p>
    </label>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#myChoices p {
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

`p` tag is block element, now we changed to inline-block,

as you are using bootstrap, you can use following classes to fix the wrap issue

add `col-xs-12` class to #myChoices div tag

add `col-xs-2` class to all span.outer tags

add `col-xs-10` class to `p` tag, if `p` tag is not possible wrap `p` tag in `div`

Example [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yajxro)

Comment: The challenge with that approach is that when the text wraps, it goes under the radio button. It's not inline with the first line of the label.